# $X - Y$ uniform on $[-1, 1]$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Can we find $X, Y$ two random variables, which are i.i.d., such that $X - Y$ is uniform on $[-1, 1]$ ?

I tried using characteristic functions, but I could not get anything from that.

Could you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Ummm... let $Y \sim \delta(0)$ and $X \sim {\cal U}[-1,1]$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork those would not be i.i.d.

Comment: Maybe it is not clear, but when I say i.i.d. I mean $X$ and $Y$ must be independent and with the same law.

Comment: Indeed you can use the characteristic function (CF) to derive the contradiction. To begin with, show that the CF of $X - Y$ is always non-negative. Then show that the CF of $\operatorname{Uniform}(-1,1)$ is $t\mapsto\operatorname{sinc} t$.

Comment: @SangchulLee But since I am working on $[-1, 1]$, where sinc is positive, how would that be a contradiction ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork i.i.d. stands for "independent and identically distributed".

Comment: @JackEight, Umm... Is $\operatorname{sinc} t$ positive *for all* $t$?

Comment: @SangchulLee right, I made the mistake of only looking at $t \in [-1, 1]$, this was stupid. Thank you ! I just need to try and understand why the CF is non-negative then.

Comment: And I understand it now.

Comment: @DominikKutek, The CF of a symmetric distribution is *real* (but not necessarily non-negative). I guess you are confusing yourself with the *symmetrized* distribution, which the distribution of $X-Y$ for some i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Indeed, thank you. My brain doesn't work well now, as we can see.

Comment: @DominikKutek, No problem, I also do lots of mistakes :)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm sure that your work is interesting, and i might just have to read that book one day. Concerning the meaning of "i.i.d." it is worth mentioning, that the term has a use both in Probability Theory, where it litterally means "independent and identically distributed" and in particular it implies "identically distributed", and it has a use in Statistics, where it as you say usually refers to the samples, that are chosen.  As the word "sample" is nowhere mentioned in the question, i find it hard to see how one can misinterpret the meaning in JackEight's question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not that wikipedia is the most reliable source of information, but here is an example of a definition that disagrees with your use of the term "i.i.d" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables#Definition_for_two_random_variables
I wish you a very nice weekend.

Comment: Have not read all the comments above. But the point is if $X, Y$ are i.i.d., then $X-Y$ is a symmetric distribution about $0$ - the probability of $X - Y$ being negative is non-zero (exclude the degenerate / constant case). So it cannot have a support on $(0, 1)$. Maybe you need to consider $(-1, 1)$ instead